# Listing procedure parameters in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am able to retrieve a list of all procedures by querying **dba_procedures**. However I am only able to extract the procedure names. But I also need their parameters.

Now, I know that I can access the *"text source of the stored objects accessible to the current user"* by querying the [all_source](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2063.htm#i1588578) table.

However is there any other way to retrieve the parameters of a procedure?

Comment: There is no `db_procedures` view or table in Oracle

Comment: @Ben meant DBA_PROCEDURES

Comment: Sorry - yes, I meant DBA_PROCEDURES. Thanks Mark. Edited my post with correction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can query the parameters using SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS Table:

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.ALL_ARGUMENTS WHERE 
  PACKAGE_NAME = '<null_or_package_name>' AND 
  OBJECT_NAME = '<procedure_name>';
```

Answer (score 2):

From SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, you can use the `DESCribe procedure_name`  command:

```
Oracle> desc dbms_metadata
FUNCTION ADD_TRANSFORM RETURNS NUMBER
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 HANDLE                         NUMBER                  IN
 NAME                           VARCHAR2                IN
 ENCODING                       VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT
 OBJECT_TYPE                    VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT
FUNCTION CHECK_MATCH_TEMPLATE RETURNS NUMBER
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 POBJNO                         NUMBER                  IN
 SPCNT                          NUMBER                  IN
...
```

Comment: @road242 answer gives you complete information; if you want a quick and summarized list, DESCribe proc_name usually gives you what you need.